# Anything wrong with disabling the Windows Search process?

Tags: windows-10, process

I noticed the 'Windows search filter host' running strong on my CPU at random times, 'indexing' files - not sure what that means really - so I googled a bit and apparently some people actually disable this process via the 'services.msc' panel.

Does it affect my system in any way if I disable it ?

[image]

Comment: You want to disable Windows Search entirely?  If you disable it you won't be able to search for files.

Comment: Yes, well, i don't need to search for files. All my work is inside a single, well-organized, folder called 'Work' so I pretty much know where everything is. Also, I never use Win's File Explorer thing to search for anything, I use Total Commander which has its own search feature.

Comment: By disabling the service in question you disable your ability to search for files using File Explorer.

Comment: So, if i'm NOT searching files with the File Explorer (literally, never using it), should I expect any other 'side effects' of having this process disabled ?

Comment: You may wish to figure out what is wrong with your computer. I have had Windows Search (and so Indexing) running on XP, Vista, Seven, Eight, and Ten none stop with no ill effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not stop the searching function, but no longer indexes new files.

I Just disabled it and stopped the service and Windows search still works.

Comment: Yes, indeed, one day after turning this off, my laptop is more quiet, with no more random overheating from this on and off indexing process.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it affect my system in any way if I disable it?

By disabling the service in question you will disable your ability to search for indexed files using File Explorer.

This will also disable your ability to perform searches within Outlook.

Answer (score -1):

It's absurd that I have to offer an answer in order to supply this information--which would be better suited as a comment:

It's highly likely that third-party file managers (like Total Commander or Explorer++) utilize the [Windows Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Search) functionality for their own search functions. As Ramhound points out, disabling Windows Search will prevent the search functionality from working, which may impact these other file managers (indeed, any third-party application which uses Windows Search, of which there may be many).

That being said, I've disabled it myself in the past, and it didn't break anything *permanently*. You should probably be fine, but if you notice applications acting oddly a month from now, you know who to blame.

Comment: The thing is, Total Commander does not do any automatic indexing by default, unless you install some third party plugin (which I don't use). TC has a manual search feature and when you run that, it actually, physically searches for files without any previous indexing. I am totally fine with this, as my file structure in not too complicated and searching takes 1-2 seconds in TC, versus the useless (for me) Windows Search, which overheats my laptop 4 times a day indexing stuff.